# Pandoc conversion from Mediawiki to GFM

Tags: mediawiki, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

Facing issues while trying to convert MediaWiki file using Pandoc to GitHub Flavored Markdown, we have some templates like showing below:

```
{|cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding = &quot;10&quot; style=&quot;border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;
| Some text....
|}
```

The script fail with the error:

```
Error at "source" (line 156, column 19):
unexpected "c"
expecting lf new-line, "!", "<" or "|"
{|cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "10" style="border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;" width="100%"
                  ^
```

- **Tool** Pandoc 2.0.1.1
- **Input** xml file exported from MediaWiki 1.21.2
- **Output** Markdown file

```shell
pandoc --from=mediawiki --to=gfm C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/pandoc5c93ace7d42b7
```

Any suggestions, thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc cannot read the exported XML, but only the actual MediaWiki markup. The markup is exported *as part* of the XML, but has to be extracted via an XML processor if one wants to feed it into pandoc.

Look for the element(s) `/mediawiki/page[ns=0]/revision/text` (XPath).

Comment: Actually from MediaWIki to GFM works fine and parsed correctly, the problem is pandoc not handling some character from the exported file using **Special:Export**, like the space before the equal sign.
For example instead of cellpadding = &quot;10&quot; it must be cellpadding=&quot;10&quot;

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, then. Sounds like a bug; please raise on https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues or post to the pandoc-discuss mailing list.

Comment: @hb.Sara tarleb is right, you seem to have `&quot;` in your input: that's not valid mediawiki, but escaped quotes as part of an XML fragment.